# How do I determine branch coverage (from a control flow graph)?

Tags: java, testing, code-coverage

I have the following piece of code (doesn't matter if it's a good method or not):

```
public boolean adjacent(Cell otherCell) {

  boolean result;
  boolean xdiffersone = Math.abs(getX() - otherCell.getX()) == 1;
  boolean ydiffersone = Math.abs(getY() - otherCell.getY()) == 1;

  if((xdiffersone && !ydiffersone) || (!xdiffersone && ydiffersone)) {

    result = true;
  }
  else {
    result = false;
  }

  return result;
}
```

The control flow graph of this method:

[image: control flow graph]

I know that statement coverage means whether all the nodes in a control flow graph have been executed/visited. But what exactly is branch coverage? How can I calculate/see that from a control flow graph (or from the code)?

Comment: Your graph can be used to compute condition coverage; branch coverage is much simpler, in your program there are only two branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statement coverage is about graph nodes.  Branch coverage is about graph edges.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Emma](http://emma.sourceforge.net/) the java code coverage tool. There are plugin to [eclipse](http://www.eclemma.org/), to maven and stand alone product named [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) that uses Emma inside and checks the code coverage. So you can use Emma either directly or indirectly.

Comment: Yes, I've used Emma, but as you can see I tagged "exam" :)